# How to override contrast in Angular Material 15 for mat-button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to have a light orange button with white text and a light hover. I created my custom color palette with contrast settings, unfortunately I still have black text in the button and dark hover and ripple :/

[image]

It seems that angular material has some kind of contrast detection and it decides what text color to use, how to overwrite it?

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$dark-primary-text: rgba(black, 0.87);
$light-primary-text: white;

$custom-amber-palette: (
  50: #fff8e1,
  100: #ffecb3,
  200: #ffe082,
  300: #ffd54f,
  400: #ffca28,
  500: #ffc107,
  600: #ffb300,
  700: #ffa000,
  800: #ff8f00,
  900: #ff6f00,
  A100: #ffe57f,
  A200: #ffd740,
  A400: #ffc400,
  A700: #ffab00,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $light-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $light-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $dark-primary-text,
    A400: $dark-primary-text,
    A700: $light-primary-text,
  ),
);

$my-primary: mat.define-palette($custom-amber-palette, 700);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$grey-palette, 900);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $my-primary,
      accent: $my-accent,
    ),
    typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
    density: 0,
  )
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26056) in Angular 15.